# How to force declaration of variables in base class

Tags: c#, .net, class, inheritance

i have a class Base and a class that inherits Base, A

```
public class Base
{
   int baseVal;
      public Base()
      {
      }
}

public class A : Base
{
    int aVal;
       public A()
      {
      }
}
```

How, when i create a variable of type A, can i make sure baseVal is also initialised?

There is one possibility, where i have the A constructor also execute a Base constructor, as in:

```
public A() : base(0)
```

but i know the value of baseVal after executing the A() constructor. So, what are my best options?

Comment: What do you mean by "I know the value of baseVale after executing the A() constructor"? Your question is very unclear.

Comment: in c++ for example: if you have a virtual abstract method in an interface, you have to initialise it in classes that inherit it. @JonSkeet

Comment: Yes, and that's what abstract *methods* are for in C#, but there's no such thing as an abstract *field*, and I don't understand how your comment answers my question about "I know the value of baseVale"

Comment: if you init a class through public A() : base(var) that implies that you first run the base(var) constructor and after the A constructor. in the case that i calculate var in the A constructor that implies that the base(var) was already executed so, i can't ensure that i init the base constructor in the manner that you can be sure that certain variables are initialised in the way you want. I know i'm not being very clear @JonSkeet

Comment: Well you need to call `base(SomeCalculation())` then. It would really help if you'd give us a concrete problem to work with...

Answer (score 1):

If by "i know the value of baseVal after executing the A() constructor" you mean that you calculate the value in constructor of class A, then you can change the baseVal accessibility to protected and assign the value at the end of the constructor in class A:

```
public class Base
{
    protected int baseVal;
    // code ommitted
}

public class A : Base
{
    int aVal;
    public A()
    {
        // calculate the value that you need
        baseVal = //some value that you calculate
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't have a empty constructor
If if it is protected it can be access by derived class

```
public class Base
{
      protected int baseVal;
      public Base(int BaseVal)
      {
          baseVal = BaseVal;
      }
}
```